# Do I need to reapply for a DS-160 if I had it before?

Tags: visas, usa, international-travel, b1-b2-visas, turkish-citizens

I am a Turkish citizen who had an F-1 visa until the Summer of 2016, since I was a student in USA. Now I will need to travel to US for a conference and will apply for a B-1/B-2 visa soon.

Do I need to apply for DS-160 again or not?

Comment: DS-160 is the form you use to apply for a visa. It is not something you need to apply for itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DS-160 is the name for a US Nonimmigrant Visa application form. It's what you need to fill out (electronically) to apply for a visa (unless you're immigrating to the US and are applying for an immigrant visa, at which point you need a DS-260 instead). You'll need to submit one (online) every time you apply for a visa.

As noted in [the FAQ](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/forms/ds-160--online-nonimmigrant-visa-application/frequently-asked-questions.html), it is possible to retrieve some of your personal information so you don't need to retype all the bits that haven't changed, though you are still responsible for ensuring that all information is correct and up-to-date:

> **I apply for U.S. visas often. Can I reuse the DS-160?**
>
> Yes, you can use information from a previously submitted DS-160 to populate some fields on a new form. There are two ways that you can do
>   this. First, if you plan to apply for a visa in the future, save your
>   DS-160 to your hard drive or a disk using the instructions in the FAQ
>   above. When you go to apply for your new visa you can then select
>   “Option B-Upload a Previously Saved Application” on the Getting
>   Started page. Alternately, if your previous visa application was
>   submitted after November 1, 2010, you can select “Option C-Retrieve
>   Application,” enter your previous visa application ID, and then hit
>   “Create a New Application.” Your personal information will then
>   populate the form. Be careful to check that all previously submitted
>   information is current and accurate.

Answer (score 1):

AT Times situations change so i personally dont think that your living two years back is the same as to date so . you can use some information used in your DS160 before and then fill in the most correct current information about you. because this is the best of you not anyone else.